# Creating Apple iPhone/iPod-Like Icons

Tags: iphone, images, batch, icons, processing

What is the best way to create apple iPhone/iPod shaped icons, ideally there should be a website that you can upload images to and have an them shaped to the default shape, etc.

Does this exists? What is the best way to great these icons?

I did find this: http://elitebydesign.com/design-the-itunes-icon-for-the-iphone-and-ipod-touch/

But there should be a batch type program out there somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to this [**iPhone / iTouch icon generator**](http://www.flavorstudios.com/iphone-icon-generator).

Strangely, I could not upload an image with Firefox, I had to use IE.

Answer (score 4):

This probably doesn't answer your question but <strike>I *think* that if you are developing iPhone apps and have the SDK</strike> if you add a 'flat' graphic <strike>and it</strike> then iPhone OS does most of the work for you - i.e. rounds the corners and adds the glossy effect meaning they all take on a standard look. See Fig 11-1 and 11-2 in [Creating Custom Icons and Images](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html).

Having said that, I've seen (literally) one or two apps that have non standard shaped icons so maybe there's a way around using the SDK method.

Like I said, this is just what I *think* happens based on reading about app development.

Comment: (Related, but also interesting: guidelines for Mac OS X icons at http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIcons/XHIGIcons.html)

Comment: (@andygrunt, feel free to remove the strikethrough, of course!)

Comment: Nah, I'll leave it - it tells the story :)

Comment: Essentially, this is true -- the iPhone itself will do all the work. However, there is a flag you can set while developing that forgoes the automatic work. The automatic work, as of the current rev, is to round off the corners and add the glossy effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty much be certain that *all* of the icon designers employed by Apple are sitting around their shiny aluminum cased Macs, running, you guessed it [Adobe Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop/family/). This is what you saw in the tutorial that you posted.

With Photoshop, you can create layer styles that will create button like that with 1-click. You can record actions (essentially macros), as well as create [scripts](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting/) via AppleScript, VBScript, and JavaScript.

Or, you can just cheat and get one of the various [Photoshop Wow!](http://www.design-bookshelf.com/Photoshop/WOW/index.html) books.